# how to send_data or attached file with goliath and grape?

Tags: goliath, grape-api

not sure how this is done, but following how's its done in Sinatra wouldn't cut it on Goliath - [How can I send binary data from Sinatra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083974/how-can-i-send-binary-data-from-sinatra)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the 'Content-Type' header into the headers hash and then just send the data back, if your file is small enough.

```
[200, {'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream'}, "\x01\x02\x03"]
```

If the file is large, you can do chunked streaming of the response, take a look in the examples directory of Goliath to see a couple of streaming samples.